# Finding the number of column in a table

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to know how to tell the number of columns in a table created in *iReport*. The variable **COLUMN_COUNT** returns the number of rows, but I want to know the number of columns.

Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: What is the reason to have column number ? I you have any significant reason for it, there is workaround for it by naming columns field as numbers etc ...

Answer (score 1):

The quotes from [***JasperReports Ultimate Guide***](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf):

    `BUILT-IN REPORT VARIABLES
        COLUMN_NUMBER

    This variable contains the current column number. For example, on a report with three
    columns, the possible values are 1, 2, and 3. The variable restarts from 1 and runs up to
    the defined number of columns for each page in the generated document.
    

    

    COLUMN_COUNT

    This variable contains the number of records that were processed when generating the
    current column.
    

    

    PAGE_NUMBER

    This variable’s value is its current page number. At the end of the report-filling process,
    it will contain the total number of pages in the document. It can be used to display both
    the current page number and the total number of pages using a special feature of
    JasperReports text field elements, the evaluationTime attribute. You can see this
    happening in most of the samples. Check the /demo/samples/jasper sample for an
    example.
    

    

    REPORT_COUNT

    After finishing the iteration through the data source, this report variable contains the total
    number of records processed.
    

    

    PAGE_COUNT

    This variable contains the number of records that were processed when generating the
    current page.
    

    

    GroupName_COUNT

    When declaring a report group, the engine automatically creates a count variable that
    calculates the number of records that make up the current group (that is, the number of
    records processed between group ruptures).
    The name of this variable is derived from the name of the group it corresponds to,
    suffixed with the _COUNT sequence. It can be used like any other report variable, in any
    report expression, even in the current group expression, as shown in the BreakGroup
    group of the /demo/samples/jasper sample).`